# What does PROCESS_MITIGATION_STRICT_HANDLE_CHECK_POLICY do?

Tags: c++, security, winapi, windows-10

I'm trying to understand process security mitigation policies introduced in Windows 10. Say, `PROCESS_MITIGATION_STRICT_HANDLE_CHECK_POLICY` I'm assuming should raise an exception when a bad handle is used. So I'm testing it as such:

```
bool bEnableIt = true;  //false

BOOL bR;
PROCESS_MITIGATION_STRICT_HANDLE_CHECK_POLICY pmshcp = {0};
pmshcp.RaiseExceptionOnInvalidHandleReference = bEnableIt;
pmshcp.HandleExceptionsPermanentlyEnabled = bEnableIt;
bR = ::SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessStrictHandleCheckPolicy, &pmshcp, sizeof(pmshcp));

HANDLE hF = (HANDLE)0x1111;
::CloseHandle(hF);          //Fake handle

hF = ::CreateFile(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
::CloseHandle(hF);
::CloseHandle(hF);          //Double closing
```

But in both cases whether I enable or disable it, or don't call `SetProcessMitigationPolicy` at all, I'm getting this exception on both `CloseHandle` calls when called on a bad handle:

[image]

So what am I missing here?

PS. I'm calling it from a 64-bit process on Windows 10.

Comment: you do this under debugger. under debugger system always do this on bad handle close. test without debugger

Comment: @RbMm: OK, I see your point. Thanks. I just compiled it as `Release` build and ran it (no debugger.) (I added a small `printf()` statement after it to see if it gets to that point.) Well, that way the exception never seems to get triggered even if I enable that mitigation policy. (My printf() always prints.) So what's the catch?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. I'm not sure why, but it seems to work with `ReadFile` but not with `CloseHandle`. (With or without a debugger.) Maybe Microsoft see no harm of calling `CloseHandle` on a bad handle.

Comment: yes, can be and more simply test `SetEvent((HANDLE)MAXLONG);` for example